# How to properly apply filter for the query presented?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parameters

I have a table as under

```
declare @t table(bucket bigint null)

insert into @t select 1 union all select 2 union all select -1 union all select 5
```

Now let me write the below query *(filter by Bucket 0  - All values are coming)*

```
declare @Bucket bigint = 0 –filter by 0

select * from @t
where 1=1
AND (@Bucket is Null or @Bucket ='' or bucket=@Bucket)

Result
1
2
-1
5
```

But if I filter Bucket by 2 or any other value, I get the results properly

```
declare @Bucket bigint = 2 –filter by 2
select * from @t
where 1=1
AND (@Bucket is Null or @Bucket ='' or bucket=@Bucket)

Result
2
```

If I filter by null or blank I get proper result

```
declare @Bucket bigint = '' –filter by ''

select * from @t
where 1=1
AND (@Bucket is Null or @Bucket ='' or bucket=@Bucket)

Result
1
2
-1
5
```

Why this behavior for bucket 0? And how to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `@Bucket bigint = NULL` for `@Bucket` default value.

> because `NULL` mean unknow

or you can set a value which should not in `bucket` column be the default value.

```
declare @Bucket bigint = NULL

select * 
from @t
where (@Bucket is Null or bucket = @Bucket)
```

**NOTE**

but If `@Bucket bigint` is bigint it should not be `''`

---

**Edit**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   Bucket bigint
);

declare @Bucket bigint = 0

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (-1);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (0);


select * from T
where  (@Bucket is Null or (@Bucket ='' and @Bucket <> 0)  or bucket=@Bucket)
```

Comment: in the db bucket is declared as BigInt. And Application is sending blank(''). And I can't change any of those. I have already tried the query you presented .  any other way provided we can't change the existing DB or FE values ?

Comment: To give you a better understanding, pls consider this Stored proc :  -- exec usp_mysp '','','','','','0',''. It will behave in dynamic way. the declaration is ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_mysp]
(
   @Product NVARCHAR(200) = '' 
  ,@Region NVARCHAR(100) = ''
  ,@State NVARCHAR(100) = ''  
  ,@City NVARCHAR(100) = '' 
  ,@Branch NVARCHAR(100) = '' 
  ,@Bucket bigint = NULL 
  ,@Staff  NVARCHAR(200) = ''
)

Comment: OK. But if we filter by blank(''') or null we should get all the values. The present query is not doing so. Rest OK

Comment: I would suggest you modify your default value because  `declare @Bucket bigint = ''` Implicit translate to `0`
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f2b4775ce2388a4861c2ac18686c27fc

Comment: or could you accept let  Bucket  be varchar `declare @Bucket VARCHAR(50)  = ''?`

Comment: thanks for the simple solution. somehow didn't strike

Answer (score 0):

FIXED

```
declare @t table(bucket bigint);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (-1);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (0);

declare @Bucket bigint = 0 --filter by 0

select * from @t
where 1=1
AND (@Bucket is Null or cast(@Bucket as nvarchar) = '' or bucket=@Bucket)
```

Comment: If we filter by 0, there won't be any record. Your query yields all records